# how to set single file in ng-flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flow-js

I need to use the single-file attribute in the ng-flow, i have to use it because this attribute other than limits the nuber of file to send, substitute the file thate was added until the upload event, see this:

```
singleFile Enable single file upload. Once one file is uploaded,
second file will overtake existing one, first one will be canceled. (Default: false)
```

this is the documentation taken from flow.js git repository.
What i really need to do is to put this attribute in the factory, because i need to set this for all my input file field. I have try to search it in the ng-flow documentation, but it lack of a lot of explanaion, anyone know how to do this? Otherwise anyone know where to find a complete good docummentation of this module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try setting it like this:

```
.config(['flowFactoryProvider', function (flowFactoryProvider) {
    flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
        singleFile: true
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 16):

Or using a tag like this:

```html
<div flow-init="{target: '/upload', singleFile: true}"></div>
```

Comment: I like your option over @TheHouseplant. It keeps the code clean and encapsulates behaviour within the directive usage.